# Theorem on normal singularities from Badescu's Algebraic Surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, k3-surfaces

Reading Lucian Badescu's Algebraic Surfaces I have encountered a proof I can't understand. That's Theorem 3.28 (M. Artin) at pages 41/42:

**Theorem 3.28 (M. Artin).** Let $(Y, y)$ be a two-dimensional normal singularity, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a desingularization of $(Y, y)$.
If $(Y, y)$ is a rational singularity, $Z$ is the fundamental cycle of the fiber
$E = f^{- 1}(y)_{red} = E_1 +··· +E_n$, and $m$ is the maximal ideal of the local
ring $O_{Y,y}$, then $X  \times_Y Spec(O_{Y,y},m^n) = nZ, H^0(O_{nZ}) \cong O_{Y,y}/m^n$, and
$\dim_k(m^n /m^{n+1}) = -n · (Z^2) + 1$ for every $n \ge 1$.

About used notations: $(Y, y)$ be a *normal singularity of an algebraic surface* $Y$ means that the normal algebraic surface (= $k$-scheme) is everywhere smooth, exept in the singular point $y$. In addition we assume $k$ algebraically closed of arbitrary characeristic.

A desingularization of $(Y, y)$ is a morphism $f : X \to Y$ such that $X$ is nonsingular surface in a
neighborhood of $f^{- 1} (y)$ and f is an isomorphism between $X \backslash f^{- 1} (y)$ and $Y \backslash \{y\}$.

The *fundamental cycle* is defined in 3.20 page 36/37.

The proof: We may obviously assume that $Y = Spec(A)$, with $A = O_{Y,y}$, because
even though in that case $X$ is no longer a projective surface, the
self-intersection of the divisor $Z$ on $X$ still makes sense, as $Z$ is still a projective
curve.

In the next step the proof shows $m^n O_X = O_X(-nZ)$ for all $ n \ge 1$. [...] This part I understand.

Then Badscu uses two isomorphisms which I not understand:

(i) $m^n \cong H^0(m^nO_X)$

(ii) $A \cong H^0(O_X)$

Why are they true?

The (ii) I think I can solve: $Y,X$ are *normal* and therefore $A=H^0(Y)= H^0(Y \backslash \{y\})= H^0(X \backslash f^{- 1} (y))=H^0(X)$ by [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BCS). The equality (i) is harder. Consider only case $n=1$. When $H^0(O_X) \otimes_A m = H^0(mO_X)$ is true?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f:X\to Y$ is a proper morphism with connected fiber, we have $$f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y.$$ Then (2) is obtained just by taking global section, using the assumption that $Y$ being affine: $$H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=H^0(Y,f_*\mathcal{O}_X)=H^0(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)=A.$$

For (1), by projection formula, $\mathfrak{m}^n\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathfrak{m}^n\otimes f_*\mathcal{O}_X=f_*(f^*\mathfrak{m}^n\otimes\mathcal{O}_X)$. Now take global section and we are done.

Comment: About your argument using projection formula I'm not sure: It says: Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an finite *locally free* $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module. Then projection formula says $\mathcal{E} \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_ Y} f_*\mathcal{F} \cong f_*(f^*\mathcal{E} \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_ X} \mathcal{F})$. In our case $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{E}$ should be $\mathfrak{m}^n$. Problem: Is $\mathfrak{m}^n$ locally free?

Comment: @katalaveino You are right, maximal ideal is not (locally) free for codimension two set. I have falsely used the projection formula. I will fix it soon.